# MAP scalar function issue in Ksqldb

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a custom UDF function (check_error) that takes Map<String, String> as input. In KSQL stream, I am creating a MAP and giving input to the UDF.

```
CREATE STREAM CHECK (VAL1 STRING, VAL2 DECIMAL(3,0)) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='CHECK', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
select MAP('VAL1' := VAL1, 'VAL2' := CAST(VAL2 as STRING)) from CHECK emit changes;
```

Below is the insert into statements that I used for checking purposes. When any one of the value out of `VAL1` and `VAL2` is `NULL`, the whole output from MAP becomes `null`.

```
insert into check (VAL1, VAL2) VALUES ('my name', 123);
insert into check (VAL2) VALUES (123);
insert into check (VAL1) VALUES ('my name');
```

Actual Output -

```
{VAL1=my name, VAL2=123}
null
null
```

Preferred Output -

```
{VAL1=my name, VAL2=123}
{VAL1=null, VAL2=123}
{VAL1=my name, VAL2=null}
```

**Here `null` is not a string**

Is this a feature of `MAP` function in KSQLDB that whenever one of the values in a key is `null` it will make the whole map as `null`? Is there a way to get the preferred output? I have checked and tried multiple things but not able to get the preferred output.

If I use the `IFNULL` function, then I am able to get the whole dictionary in the output but not the preferred output.

```
select map('VAL1' := IFNULL(val1, 'null'), 'VAL2' := CASE WHEN val2 IS NULL THEN 'null' WHEN val2 IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(val2 AS STRING) END) from check emit changes;

Output - 
{VAL1=my name, VAL2=123}
{VAL1=null, VAL2=123}
{VAL1=my name, VAL2=null}
```

**NOTE: Here the `null` is a STRING**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the desired output using `AS_MAP()` scalar function instead of the `MAP` datatype of KSQL like I was doing in the question.

New KSQL query used -

```
select AS_MAP(ARRAY['VAL1', 'VAL2'], ARRAY[VAL1, CAST(VAL2 as STRING)]) from CHECK emit changes;
```

`ARRAY` is used to convert into `list` as the `AS_MAP` function takes `list` in its input.